# Would MongoDB take a datetime object with missing fields?

Tags: mongodb, datetime, pymongo, isodate

Right now I have a datetime object, but it doesn't contain all the fields. It's missing minutes, seconds, and microseconds. I want to use this to fetch data from MongoDB through Python. i'm just wondering if pymongo will automatically fill in the missing fields and convert it into ISODATE, or it's going to produce an error?

EDIT:
an example:

```
time1='2015-12-17 23'
#assuming already imported all necessary libs
time2=datetime.strptime(time1, '%Y-%m-%d %H')
#for mongo
sq = {'$and': [something.some, {'field1':{'ne':1}}]}
sq['$and'].append({'field2': {'$gt': time2}})
```

Comment: You should post some examples of what you tried already. From my experience, if you have only for instance: 2015-12-17 c# for instance will fill the Datetime object with leading zeros: 2015-12-17 00:00:00. My best guess is that it will convert to that and than to ISODATE.

Comment: @jpgrassi edited my post. Please check. Since Mongo lists everything in ISODATE, I don't know if missing the minutes and so will cause any issue.

Comment: I don't know python to help you.. but that 'H' there sounds like problem to me. Where do you get the date in this format? And most important, did you actually tried to insert this in Mongo? If you are concerned if it is going to work or not, the better way to discover is doing it!

Comment: this time string is from a user input. Maybe I should try adding some 0's for minutes and seconds then convert to datetime object

Comment: That is what I probably would do. And I imagine that if you only pass the date part (2015-12-14) to a Datetime object, it will do that for you (fill with zeros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, there's no such thing as a datetime object with missing fields. All the datetime fields (relevant to this question) always have values.

The way you created `time2`, the fields you didn't specify get the value 0, as demostrated here:

```
% time2
=> datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 17, 23, 0)
% time2.minute, time2.second, time2.microsecond
=> (0, 0, 0)
time2 == datetime(2015, 12, 17, 23, 0,0,0)
=> True
```

As demostrated above, your `time2` object is *identical* to the object you would have gotten if were manually filling the values with zeros.

Now that you see your datetime object is not missing anything, it should be clear how mongodb treats it.